# It is not a hotspot, it was made to look like one while attacking my network

Tags: network

It is my first time posting on this forum, so correct me if I do things incorrectly.

My ISP is Xfinity. I use their modem/router. I have been noticing unusual activities from  my network and an unknown ssid broadcasting from my modem. **As a test, I disabled my wifi ( both 2.4 and 5) and my hotspot, so that the only internet coming from my modem was through ethernet** yet, strange things kept on happening,  such as:

1. unknown device on my network that will show in the 10.0.0.1 page
2. The 10.0.0.1 page will not show current connected and trusted devices sometime, such as my own computer connected via ethernet.
3. the modem will enable and disable functions, such bridge mode, disable ssid broadcast, enable wifi **It will do this by itself, not by my commands but by itself, please take that into consideration**
4. **Despite having disabling wifi and hotspot in 10.0.0.1, the modem lights will start flashing by themselves and an unknown ssid ( a secured connection named XFINITY) will start broadcasting.** I think it was meant to make it look like a hotspot but hotspot are open to all devices connection, not a secured connection ( requiring username and password). It stops broadcasting when I turn off the modem and starts broadcasting again when I turn the modem back on.
5. changing the passwords on both Xfinity account and 10.0.0.1 page does not seem to have fixed the problem.

What could I do to fix all of those symptoms ?Thank you for any suggestions that can provided.

Comment: This reads more like a question on how network devices function, and less like a security question. I would suggest [Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) for this question.

Comment: Thank you for your input Vidarlo. I edited the title and made sure to point out that the intrusion was made to look like a hotspot was broadcasting even though I had disabled that feature months before the incident. At the time of the incident, I had disabled wifi and Hotspot on the modem/router and changed the passwords on wifi and accounts ( modem interface and xfinity account) yet the hacker was able to enable the features on the modem and broadcast an ssid different from the ones that I had set in place ( different than my 2.4 and 5 ssids)

Comment: Don't use Comcast/XFinity myself or have any internal insight, so this is just a guess. Part of the reason that XFinity provides the hotspot feature is so their field technicians/installers have a better chance of having access. By disabling the publicly available hotspot, your device may start a non-public network to which only their employees have access (and you cannot disable). This would likely be why it has a slightly different name than the public network and shows up as a secured network. That way their field employees don't lose the opportunity to be connected when nearby.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like some (or all) of what you are seeing may be related to the fact that Comcast/XFinity uses it's customers' routers to provide public wifi access.  See the following links for more information, including how to disable this on your router:

https://money.cnn.com/2014/06/16/technology/security/comcast-wifi-hotspot/

http://wifi.xfinity.com/

https://www.xfinity.com/support/articles/disable-xfinity-wifi-home-hotspot

Comment: Thank you for answering. I had the hotspot feature disabled before the incident. The unknown ssid is also not a real hotspot. It was made to look like one. A hotspot is a network open to a all devices, not a secured connection, the one named "XFINITY" was a secured network that required a username and password( strange to me) Look for the little lock icon next to the ssid being broacasted, it tells you if it is  a secured network and a fan means an open unsecured network. Please also remember that wifi and hotspot had been disabled months before the incident. Please consider the other symptoms

Comment: You need to read the XFINITY documents closely and understand the service Comcast is operating. They operate hotspots which are secured and require authentication from your home connection. Refer to the question "What is the XFINITY WiFi Home Hotspot Feature?" at https://wifi.xfinity.com/faq.php (this hotspot is completely separate from any personal hotspot you may choose to configure)